# How to read data sent via bluetooth by an App

Tags: bluetooth, iot, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I am a developer and I have a Bluetooth Lamp that has RGB and Day/Warm Light that has a third party App to control it.

My goal is to do some automation with my Lamp.

Is there a way to read what this app is sending to my Lamp is order to simulate its functionality? The thing is this App is not possible to integrate with my Google assistant so I am trying to find a way to do it my self by making my own mobile application to control my Lamp.

Or maybe my question should be something like: is there a generic App that can control generic Bluetooth Lamps?

Any information is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could either hack the hardware itself, or you could simply [snoop on the communications](https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/bt-recon-snoop-bluetooth-devices-using-kali-linux-0165049/) to hack in to the lamp controls.

Otherwise, I would check out integration platforms like [IFTTT](http://ifttt.com/), which allows some customization of control with proprietary systems.